# Vaadin & Apache Shiro - Session Expired

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin, shiro, vaadin7

User logs in ok, logs out ok, but if he immediately makes another attempt to log in (input login/pass + enter) he receives popup

```
Session Expired
Take note of any unsaved data, and click here or press ESC key to continue.
```

Log in operation handled by Apache Shiro:

```
Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
currentUser.login(new UsernamePasswordToken(event.getLogin(), event.getPassword()));
```

Log out operation also:

```
Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
currentUser.logout();
```

After the log out user is redirected to login page and when he enters credentials again he gets the warning about expired session. Why new session is not started? How to start it? Or maybe this approach isn't correct at all?

P.S. I also tried

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().close();
```

but result was the same.

Comment: This issue is probably about your approach with Vaadin and its UI/Session, not about Shiro. Please provide the methods that are around you Shiro code.

Comment: Are you using Push? an Apache Proxy maybe?

Comment: Did you follow this section: https://vaadin.com/vaadin-documentation-portlet/framework/application/application-lifecycle.html#application.lifecycle.session-closing ?